# GridList Control Column Header Click

Tags: c#

I would like to order contents in a column when user clicks column header. Does anyone have any idea on how I might achieve this using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WinForms: [Sorting Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171607.aspx)

For ASP.NET: [Sorting Data in a GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx)